# Simple Central authentication service - navigating between services

Tags: php, web-services, authentication, single-sign-on, cas

I have multiple services available on different domains, each with their own user tables.

I am working on implementing a simple unified authentication system and Single sign on.

So far I have worked out the workflow to get the users to register/login on the CAS page and redirect them to their chosen service alongwith a authorization code.

The service then exchange the code for an access_token and gets user details and creates/updates user and logs them in.

I want to allow users to navigate to between services once they have authenticated to one of the services.

The goal is to offer seamless navigation between multiple services.

When a user navigates to another service, obviously that service will need to do its own authorization transaction with the CAS server, not sure what the nature of that transaction would look like though.

How do I create a cross-service sameless navigation between services when all the services are using a central authentication service and SSO.

Comment: You should look into oauth framework.

Comment: @HyderB. Thanks for the comment - I have looked at OAuth workflows - I have not been able to figure out how this would allow a user to navigate between multiple services

Answer (score 0):

If your services are all integrated with CAS, each service will need to contact CAS to get some kind of a token/ticket, and then ask CAS to validate it in order to receive the user profile. The actual act of authentication is only done once so that CAS can establish an SSO session, but the task of getting and validating the tickets usually is done one per app when the app decides to authenticate the user (because its session expires, etc).

The same concept works more or less the same regardless of the authentication protocol. (OAuth, CAS, etc). This more or less assumes your services are web-based where the browser is involved. If you have services proxying other backend services, then the same solution would be slightly more complicated.